# How can I get rid of visual studio code's auto formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I block visual studio code from auto formatting on save?

It causes chaos to the git commit!

The blanks which are auto generated by this software, which have nothing to do with the function improvements, are messed up with the real useful code.

How can I get rid of this auto formatting?

Comment: Open `Settings` and search for `format`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings and search 'format'. There's an option there called "Editor: Format On Save". Turn this off, and it should disable the auto-formatting.